# Modules with Classes and Imports

Tags: python, python-module

If I were to use a class in a module how would I make it "top level" in it's instance?

Structure:

```
/package
    __init__.py
    /subPackage
        __init__.py
        module.py
        subModule.py
    /theScript.py
```

`python theScript.py`

Source of theScript:

```
import package.subPackage.module
package.subPackage.module.method()
```

Source of /package/subPackage/module.py:

```
class module:
    def method(self): pass
moduleInstance = module()
```

I guess what I am asking is how would I make it so that I don't have to do `package.subPackage.module.moduleInstance.method()` and could `package.subPackage.module.method()`

I know I can just remove the class and instance but I prefer the class because it makes it easier to subclass later if somebody wants to without needing to modify our source directly but if I ultimately have to I will just use methods instead of class/method in module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how the [`random` module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/65c412586901/Lib/random.py#l705) in the standard lib solved this problem:

```
_inst = Random()
seed = _inst.seed
random = _inst.random
uniform = _inst.uniform
triangular = _inst.triangular
...
```

Seems a reasonable solution to me.  Of course there is the drawback that you have to manually keep the method lists in sync, but the worst thing that will happen if you forget to add a method name is an error message that tells you exactly what is missing.

Comment: Is there a way to do variable variables like PHP? For example in PHP I would do $$var = $_instance->$$var()

Comment: @Jordon: While this is possible in Python at the global scope, it is frowned upon, and Python isn't meant to be used that way.  I recommend to either maintain the list manually, as the Python core maintainers do in this example, or to use an instance instead of a module in the first place (i. e. add an instance to `__init__.py` and use the instance instead of `module`.  Of course you can't do `import package.sub_package.instance` in this case since `instance` is not a module.)